Oracle SQL - Compare content of Strings
I have a request where two columns on two separate tables need to be compared.
Comparing column contents of String_to_Compare on table A vs contents of column String_to_Compare on table B. E.g. comparing 'this is a string' vs 'this is a mtrink'.
Using UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY has proven not to work, giving high ranked results to strings that are not really similar.
Any idea of what else to use?
CREATE TABLE Table_A 
(   "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 ORDER  NOCYCLE  
NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
String_to_compare varchar2(4000)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_B 
(   "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 ORDER  NOCYCLE  
NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
String_to_compare varchar2(4000)
);

insert into Table_A (String_to_compare)
values('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod diam vel 
lectus feugiat porta. Ut sit amet elit nisi. Integer at aliquam neque.')

insert into Table_A (String_to_compare)
values('Phasellus lectus purus, euismod auctor tortor ut, lacinia ornare augue. Sed 
fringilla feugiat commodo. Suspendisse leo arcu, malesuada eu maximus sit amet, 
eleifend eu urna.')

insert into Table_A (String_to_compare)
values('Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia curae')


insert into Table_B (String_to_compare)
values('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod diam vel 
lectus feugiat porta. Ut sit amet elit nisi. Integer at aliquam neque.')

insert into Table_B (String_to_compare)
values('Phasellus lectus purus, euismod auctor tortor ut, lacinia ornare augue. Sed 
fringilla feugiat commodo. Suspendisse leo arcu, malesuada eu maximus sit amet, 
eleifend eu urna.')

insert into Table_B (String_to_compare)
values('Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia curae')


For your sample data, use an INNER JOIN and match when the strings are equal (there is no need to use fuzzy matching as the strings are identical in both tables):
SELECT *
FROM   table_a a
       INNER JOIN table_b b
       ON a.string_to_compare = b.string_to_compare

Which outputs:



ID
STRING_TO_COMPARE
ID
STRING_TO_COMPARE




1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod diam vel lectus feugiat porta. Ut sit amet elit nisi. Integer at aliquam neque.
1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod diam vel lectus feugiat porta. Ut sit amet elit nisi. Integer at aliquam neque.


2
Phasellus lectus purus, euismod auctor tortor ut, lacinia ornare augue. Sed fringilla feugiat commodo. Suspendisse leo arcu, malesuada eu maximus sit amet, eleifend eu urna.
2
Phasellus lectus purus, euismod auctor tortor ut, lacinia ornare augue. Sed fringilla feugiat commodo. Suspendisse leo arcu, malesuada eu maximus sit amet, eleifend eu urna.


3
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae
3
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae



If you did want a fuzzy match then you can use:
ON UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(a.string_to_compare, b.string_to_compare) > 0.95

or:
ON UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(a.string_to_compare, b.string_to_compare) <= 1

or:
ON SOUNDEX(a.string_to_compare) = SOUNDEX(b.string_to_compare)

In the join condition and specify the accuracy of the matches to use in the joins.
fiddle

Thanks! yes, was looking for fuzzy matches. Thank you
